# Construction of a random date generator with weighted weekends in R

Tags: r, random

I am performing creel surveys and am attempting to construct a random date generator that weights the weekends higher than the weekdays. So far I have a simplistic random date generator that does not take into account the day type. We expect more angling pressure on the weekends (as that is when more people have time to fish) but do not have a way to select random days without including bias. I would like to select 15 days within a given month.

I've already generated a simplistic random date generator:

```
dates <- data.frame(seq.Date(as.Date(day.start),as.Date(day.end),by="day"))

dates

sample(dates$seq.Date.as.Date.day.start...as.Date.day.end...by....day.., size = 15, replace = FALSE)     
[1] "2019-11-10" "2019-11-06" "2019-11-04" "2019-11-27" "2019-11-30" "2019-11-15"     
[7] "2019-11-18" "2019-11-21" "2019-11-13" "2019-11-01" "2019-11-19" "2019-11-25"    
[13] "2019-11-07" "2019-11-02" "2019-11-23"
```

Ideally I would have an end product that allows me to input the month start and end and outputs 15 random days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation in comments in code below:

```
# Generate initial data; as in question
day_start <- as.Date("2010-10-01")
day_end   <- as.Date("2010-10-31")
dates <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(day_start, day_end,by="day"))

# Determine inclusion probabilities for each date; give weekend a higher 
# probability.
dates$day     <- as.numeric(format(dates$date, "%u"))
dates$psamp   <- ifelse(dates$day >= 6, 0.2, 0.1)

# Make sure probabilites add up to requires sample size
samplesize    <- 15
dates$psamp   <- dates$psamp * samplesize/sum(dates$psamp)

# Do not use sample for sampling without replacement with unequal probabilities!
# The sampling package has a large number of routines for sampling without 
# replacement and unequal probabilites. The following gives a fixed size sample
# (sum dates$psamp)
library(sampling)
dates$selected <- UPrandomsystematic(dates$psamp)
```

As for the reason why I don't use `sample` see, for example, https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-February/153601.html.

Comment: I'm curious why you recommend against using sample for unequal probabilities?

Comment: Is it due to this line? (from the `?sample` help) *"If replace is false, these probabilities are applied sequentially, that is the probability of choosing the next item is proportional to the weights amongst the remaining items. The number of nonzero weights must be at least size in this case."*

Comment: @Gregor Yes, that is is reason. I am trying to find some documentation on this.

Comment: @Gregor I did find this link, but yet the post it is refering to: https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Sampling-with-unequal-probabilities-td918656.html

Comment: @Gregor Found it: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-February/153601.html

Comment: Thanks - very interesting!

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was looking for. It allows me to weight the days of the week individually, as we were debating if Friday needs weighted differently as well. I did notice that the code dates$psamp   <- ifelse(dates$date >= 6, 0.2, 0.1) should be dates$psamp   <- ifelse(dates$day >= 6, 0.2, 0.1)

Comment: How would I go about changing my sample size if I am using this?

Comment: @joshankeny Fixed the error. Thanks for pointing that out. In  my code there is a `samplesize` variable that is now set to 15 and is used to ensure that the probabilites add up to 15.

Comment: @JanvanderLaan When I run this code after changing the sample size and the value in the probability calculation to 20 I am getting wonky selected values (1, 1.025641 and 0 ) instead of the 0 and 1 that UPrandomsystematic should output. Any ideas on a fix for this?

Comment: @joshankeny I changed the example so that the `samplesize` variable is actually used. I can reproduce the error you report when I set the sample size *higher* than 20. In that case the sample size is too high for the fact that you want the inclusion probabilities of the weekends to be twice as high as the week days. Some of the `psamp` are higher than 1. You can make the difference between `0.2` and `0. 1` smaller, or choose a smaller sample size.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *somewhat* general function that does what you want. It takes the start day, end day, and the weight (relative to 1) that you want to put on weekends as its own arguments, and passes on other additional arguments (`size`, `replace`, etc.) to `sample`. No dependencies other than base R.

However, if sampling without replacement, you may want to use the `sampling` package as recommended in Jan van der Laan's answer.

```
rday = function(
  start_day = as.Date("2019-01-01"),
  end_day = as.Date("2019-01-31"),
  weekend_weight = 2,
  ...
) {
  if (! "Date" %in% class(start_day)) start_day = as.Date(start_day)
  if (! "Date" %in% class(end_day)) end_day = as.Date(end_day)
  dates = seq(start_day, end_day, by = "1 day")
  weights = rep(1, length(dates))
  weights[weekdays(dates) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")] = 1
  sample(dates, ..., prob = weights)
}


rday(size = 15)
# [1] "2019-01-24" "2019-01-07" "2019-01-21" "2019-01-15" "2019-01-27" "2019-01-04" "2019-01-30" "2019-01-12"
# [9] "2019-01-11" "2019-01-08" "2019-01-20" "2019-01-01" "2019-01-03" "2019-01-19" "2019-01-29"
```